# vlan on desktop switches

Tags: switch, vlan

we have a large office that has around 100+ computers that are in groups of 4-6. Each group has an 6-8 port switch (mixed brands), that then connects another larger switch in each room. those switches all link to a core switch.
Currently we are not using vlans, but this is a requirement. question is: Do all switches need to be configured with vlans, or would we just need to configure vlans on the switch in each room. reason i am asking is that not all switches are managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use managed switches for everything, let's say you have a managed switch in a room that has one port going to each group (aka a cable running to a desk) which uses a "dumb" desktop switch you could let the managed switch tag/untag the packages for that specific physical port.

E.g.: Your uplink at your managed switch is Port 1 (with VLAN-tag), Ports 2-24 are linked to a group each. You could then assign VLANs to each of these (physical) ports and the switch would then automatically add and remove VLAN-tags (removing them when sending packages to the desks/"dumb" switches and adding them when sending them back to the uplink so your router/server can handle them according to their VLAN-group).

Comment: Of course in this solution your endpoints are essentially without VLAN capability, it only helps for your inner infrastructure.